# Java Enum related questions

Tags: java, enums

Can anyone please answer the below questions?

1. Can I use logical operator over enum values?
   For example:

   ```
   enum Days {
       MONDAY(1), TUESDAY(2), WEDNESDAY(3), THURSDAY(4), FRIDAY(5), SATURDAY(6), SUNDAY(7)
   }
   ```

   now can I use `if(Days.SUNDAY > Days.MONDAY)` ....?
2. Is there any process to specify a range of values for enum?
   For example, I want to specify the valid numbers for an exam should be between 1 - 100.
   So if I want to declare an enum, then it would be like this ->
   `enum Validno{ONE(1),TWO(2),....,HUNDRED(100)}`
   Now is there any option to declare an enum containing the each values and specify them like a range instead of declaring each one seperately?

   - Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible and possible.

Comment: For #1, couldn't you just have tried it?

Comment: For #2, it's not clear what you want.  Are you asking whether there's a way to generate the enum `ONE(1), TWO(2), ... HUNDRED(100)` *without* actually typing it all in to your source code?

Comment: With not just use an int for #2? It's not the best use of enums.

Comment: You better use enums for a small set. 100 values I would say it's too big to use as an enum.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, I want to mean that I don't want to type from ONE to HUNDRED one by one, instead i want to search if there is any option to instantiate the enum for a range?

Comment: @NPException: That's still not clear.  If you just want a range check, then implement a range check.  If that's not what you want, then please add some psuedocode to your question to illustrate how you'd like to *use* this "enum".

Comment: @m0skit0 my requirement is to restrict the numbers of an exam in between 0-100, then instead of enum, what should be the better choice?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth for example, I want to assign a pririty for the objects of a certain class. Now the priority should be in between 1-100 ... that's why I am thinking of using enum... but while I am writing code, I have to type ONE to HUNDRED ... that's the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you can use ordinal method as below

```
enum Day {
MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN
}

public class EnumExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Day.MON.ordinal() < Day.TUE.ordinal()); // Prints true
    System.out.println(Day.MON.ordinal() > Day.TUE.ordinal()); // Prints false
}
}
```

for #2: why do you want to use enums? You can simple comparison. 
Like for eg:

```
if(marks > 0 && marks < 100)
```

Comment: You can also use `Day.MON.compareTo(Day.TUE) > 0`. Enums automatically implement Comparable.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, yes it's possible using [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo%28E%29) method.

You could do something like this:

```
enum Days {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Days.Monday.compareTo(Days.Sunday));     // Returns negative value
    System.out.println(Days.Thursday.compareTo(Days.Tuesday));  // Returns positive value
    System.out.println(Days.Tuesday.compareTo(Days.Tuesday));   // Returns zero
}
```

For #2, 
I don't think there's a way to declare enums programatically. You will have to list down ONE to HUNDRED, if you want to use enum.

Instead, why don't you just declare a function that checks if a given score is valid or not?
It could be something like this:

```
public boolean isValid(int score){
    return score>=0 && score<=100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative for your second problem, you can simply use a regular class:

```
public final class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
    private final int value;

    public Score(int value) {
        if (value < 0 || value > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("score value must be between 0 and 100");
        } 
        this.value = value;
    } 

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // equals, hashCode and compareTo omitted, but should be there
}
```

This gives you the type safety of an enum, without the need to declare every of the 101 values independantly. No one will ever be able to create a score with an incorrect value.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion ... actually I want to assign a pririty for the objects of a certain class. Now the priority should be in between 1-100 ... that's why I am thinking of using enum... but while I am writing code, I have to type ONE to HUNDRED ... that's the problem ...